# No visible results after "Plot elevation, please wait..." message when using icepyx library

Tags: python, visualization, satellite-image

I'm trying to use the icepyx library to display elevation satellite data from NSIDC using OpenAltimetry. I changed the parameters I was using to the defaults shown on the icepyx site so I'm following their exact instructions, but still nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
import icepyx as ipx

# general range wanted
short_name = 'ATL06'
date_range = ['2020-7-1', '2020-8-1'] # change later
spatial_extent = [-67, -70, -59, -65]  # change later
cycles = ['03']
tracks = ['0948', '0872', '1184', '0186', '1123', '1009', '0445', '0369']

region = ipx.Query('ATL06',[-55, 68, -48, 71],['2019-02-22','2019-02-28'], \
start_time='00:00:00', end_time='23:59:59')

region.visualize_spatial_extent()
cyclemap, rgtmap = region.visualize_elevation()
cyclemap
```

It successfully sends the request to OpenAltimetry but simply displays "Plotting elevation, please wait..." before resetting the terminal.

I tried checking to see if the results were shown as a new file in the directory, or another instance of the application, but I didn't see anything.

I also tried using the Visualization module directly with `from icepyx.core.visualization import Visualize` and `vis = Visualize(region)` but it just reset the terminal, without a message or anything.